handling html form inside fastapi
i have a simple html file that have a navbar which include login,when the user press on login it does not redirect him to an independent page,instead it show a window for login inside that html file
however i have my html/css/js files inside a directory called static ,in fastapi i use this code to mount from that directory:
app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

so as i  understand , white this code my html file will be considered by fastapi as a static file which means it  has nothing to do with an endpoint  ,i mean for example in the login form when the user click on submit the form data will not go to /login endpoint even  if specified that in the form action,is that correct?
i have an idea which i don't like :this idea is create a separate file for login,so iam looking for a way that allow me to keep my existing html file without change and be able to handle form data in /login endpoint.
please note that i don't want to use jinja2,i heard that it reload the page each time so that's why,please tell me if am wrong.
simple fastapi code
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, WebSocket, Form, Request

from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/login")
 def log(request: Request):

app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

html form
<form action="/login" class="login-form" method="POST" >
                <div class="input-field">
                    <input class="email" type="text" required>
                    <label>Email</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field">
                    <input type="password" required>
                    <label>password</label>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="forget-password">Forgot password</a>
                <button type="submit">Log IN</button>
            </form>



In addition to the link above, I would suggest having a look at this answer and this answer, as well as every reference included in them.

This answer and this answer might also prove useful to you in the future.
